# Output to PDF doesn't print out everything

Tags: sectioning, lyx, page-breaking

I have the following text in a file:

```
1 A2:

1.1 General Information

1.1.1 About This Manual

1.1.2 Typographical and Syntax Conventions

1.1.3 Overview of the MySQL Database Management System

1.1.4 What Is New in MySQL 5.5

1.1.5 MySQL Development History

1.1.6 MySQL Information Sources

1.1.7 How to Report Bugs or Problems

1.1.8 MySQL Standards Compliance

1.1.9 Credits

1.2 Installing and Upgrading MySQL

1.2.1 General Installation Guidance

1.2.2 Installing MySQL from Generic Binaries on Unix/Linux

1.2.3 Intalling MySQL on Microsoft Windows

1.2.4 Intalling MySQL on Mac OS X

1.2.5 Intalling MySQL on Linux

1.2.6 Intalling MySQL Using Unbreakable Linux Network (ULN)

1.2.7 Intalling MySQL on Solaris and OpenSolaris

1.2.8 Intalling MySQL on HP-UX

1.2.9 Intalling MySQL on FreeBSD

1.2.10 Intalling MySQL from Source

1.2.11 Postinstallation Setup and Testing

1.2.12 Upgrading or Downgrading MySQL

1.2.13 Environment Variables

1.2.14 Perl Installation Notes

1.3 Tutorial

1.3.1 Connecting to and Disconnecting from the Server

1.3.2 Entering Queries

1.3.3 Creating and Using a Database

1.3.4 Getting Information About Databases and Tables

1.3.5 Using MySQL in Batch Mode

1.3.6 Examples of Common Queries

1.3.7 Using MySQL with Apache

1.4 MySQL Programs

1.4.1 Overview of MySQL Programs

1.4.2 Using MySQL Programs

1.4.3 MySQL Server and Server-Startup Programs

1.4.4 MySQL Installation-Related Programs

1.4.5 MySQL Client Programs

1.4.6 MySQL Administrative and Utility Programs

1.4.7 MySQL Program Development Utilities

1.4.8 Miscellaneous Programs

1.5 MySQL Server Administration

1.5.1 The MySQL Server

1.5.2 MySQL Server Logs

1.5.3 Running Multiple MySQL Instances on One Machine

1.5.4 Tracing MySQL Using DTrace

1.6 Security

1.6.1 General Security Issues

1.6.2 The MySQL Access Privilege System

1.6.3 MySQL User Account Management

1.7 Backup and Recovery

1.7.1 Backup and Recovery Types

1.7.2 Database Backup Methods

1.7.3 Example Backup and Recovery Strategy

1.7.4 Using mysqldump for Backup

1.7.5 Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery Using the Binary Log

1.7.6 MyISAM Table Maintenance and Crash Recovery

1.8 Optimization

1.8.1 Optimazation Overview

1.8.2 Optimizing SQL Statements

1.8.3 Optimization and Indexes

1.8.4 Optimizing Database Structure

1.8.5 Optimizing for InnoDB Tables

1.8.6 Optimizing MyISAM Tables

1.8.7 Optimizing for MEMORY Tables

1.8.8 Understanding the Query Execution Plan

1.8.9 Buffering and Caching

1.8.10 Optimizing Locking Operations

1.8.11 Optimizing the MySQL Server

1.8.12 Measuring Performance (Benchmarking)

1.8.13 Internal Details of MySQL Optimizations

1.9 Language Structure

1.9.1 Literal Values

1.9.2 Schema Object Names

1.9.3 Reserved Words

1.9.4 User-Defined Variables

1.9.5 Expression Syntax

1.9.6 Comment Syntax

1.10 Globalization

1.10.1 Character Set Support

1.10.2 Setting the Error Message Language

1.10.3 Adding a Character Set

1.10.4 Adding a Collation to a Character Set

1.10.5 Character Set Configuration

1.10.6 MySQL Server Time Zone Support

1.10.7 MySQL Server Locale Support

1.11 Data Types

1.11.1 Data Type Overview

1.11.2 Numeric Types

1.11.3 Data and Time Types

1.11.4 String Types

1.11.5 Data Type Default Values

1.11.6 Data Type Storage Requirements

1.11.7 Choosing the Right Type for a Column

1.11.8 Using Data Types from Other Database Engines

1.12 Functions and Operators

1.12.1 Function and Operator Reference

1.12.2 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation

1.12.3 Operators

1.12.4 Control Flow Functions

1.12.5 String Functions

1.12.6 Numeric Functions and Operators

1.12.7 Date and Time Functions

1.12.8 What Calendar Is Used By MySQL

1.12.9 Full-Text Search Functions

1.12.10 Cast Functions and Operators

1.12.11 XML Functions

1.12.12 Bit Functions

1.12.13 Encryption and Compression Functions

1.12.14 Information Functions

1.12.15 Miscellaneous Functions

1.12.16 Functions and Modifiers for Use with GROUP BY Clauses

1.12.17 Spatial Extensions

1.12.18 Precision Math

1.13 SQL Statement Syntax

1.13.1 Data Definition Statements

1.13.2 Data Manipulation Statements

1.13.3 MySQL Transactional and Locking Statements

1.13.4 Replication Statements

1.13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements

1.13.6 MySQL Compound-Statement Syntax

1.13.7 Database Administration Statements

1.13.8 MySQL Utility Statements

1.14 Storage Engines

1.14.1 Setting the Storage Engine

1.14.2 Overview of MySQL Storage Engine Architecture

1.14.3 The InnoDB Storage Engine

1.14.4 New Features of InnoDB 1.1

1.14.5 The MyISAM Storage Engine

1.14.6 The MEMORY Storage Engine

1.14.7 The CSV Storage Engine

1.14.8 The ARCHIVE Storage Engine

1.14.9 The BLACKHOLE Storage Engine

1.14.10 The MERGE Storage Engine

1.14.11 The FEDERATED Storage Engine

1.14.12 The EXAMPLE Storage Engine

1.14.13 Other Storage Engines

1.15 High Availability and Scalability

1.15.1 Oracle VM Template for MySQL Enterprise Edition

1.15.2 Using MySQL with DRBD

1.15.3 Using Linux HA Heartbeat

1.15.4 Using MySQL within an Amazon EC2 Instance

1.15.5 Using ZFS Replication

1.15.6 Using MySQL with memcached

1.15.7 MySQL Proxy

1.16 Replication

1.16.1 Replication Configuration

1.16.2 Replication Implementation

1.16.3 Replication Solutions

1.16.4 Replication Notes and Tips

1.17 MySQL Cluster NDB 7.2

1.17.1 MySQL Cluster Overview

1.17.2 MySQL Cluster Installation

1.17.3 MySQL Cluster Configuration

1.17.4 MySQL Cluster Programs

1.17.5 Management of MySQL Cluster

1.17.6 MySQL Cluster Replication

1.17.7 Changes in MySQL Cluster

1.18 Partitioning

1.18.1 Overview of Partitioning in MySQL

1.18.2 Partitioning Types

1.18.3 Partition Management

1.18.4 Partition Pruning

1.18.5 Restrictions and Limitations on Partitioning

1.19 Stored Programs and Views

1.19.1 Defining Stored Programs

1.19.2 Using Stored Routines (Procedures and Functions)

1.19.3 Using Triggers

1.19.4 Using the Event Scheduler

1.19.5 Using Views

1.19.6 Access Control for Stored Programs and Views

1.19.7 Binary Logging of Stored Programs

1.20 INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables

1.20.1 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLLATIONS Table

1.20.2 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY Table

1.20.3 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table

1.20.4 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMN_PRIVILEGES Table

1.20.5 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA ENGINES Table

1.20.6 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA EVENTS Table

1.20.7 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA GLOBAL_STATUS and SESSION_STATUS Tables

1.20.8 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA GLOBAL_VARIABLES and SESSION_VARIABLES Tables

1.20.9 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA KEY_COLUMN_USAGE Table

1.20.10 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA PARAMETERS Table

1.20.11 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA PARTITIONS Table

1.20.12 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA PLUGINS Table

1.20.13 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA PROCESSLIST Table

1.20.14 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA PROFILING Table

1.20.15 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA REFERENTIAL_CONTRAINTS Table

1.20.16 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA ROUTINES Table

1.20.17 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA SCHEMATA Table

1.20.18 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES Table

1.20.19 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA STATISTICS Table

1.20.20 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table

1.20.21 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLESPACES Table

1.20.22 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Table

1.20.23 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_PRIVILEGES Table

1.20.24 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TRIGGERS Table

1.20.25 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA USER_PRIVILEGES Table

1.20.26 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA VIEWS Table

1.20.27 INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables for InnoDB

1.20.28 INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables for MySQL Cluster

1.20.29 Thread Pool INFORMATION_SCHMA Tables

1.20.30 Extendions to SHOW Statements

1.21 MySQL Performace Schema

1.21.1 Performance Schema Quick Start

1.21.2 Performance Schema Configuration

1.21.3 Performance Schema Queries

1.21.4 Performance Schema Instrument Naming Conventions

1.21.5 Performance Schema Status Monitoring

1.21.6 Performance Schema General Table Characteristics

1.21.7 Performance Schema Table Descriptions

1.21.8 Performance Schema System Variables

1.21.9 Performance Schema Status Variables

1.21.10 Performance Schema and Plugins

1.21.11 Using the Performance Schema to Diagnose Problems

1.22 Connectors and APIs

1.22.1 MySQL Connector/ODBC

1.22.2 MySQL Connector/Net

1.22.3 MySQL Connector/J

1.22.4 MySQL Connector/C++

1.22.5 MySQL Connector/C

1.22.6 MySQL Connector/Python

1.22.7 MySQL Connector/OpenOffice.org

1.22.8 libmysqld, the Embedded MySQL Server Library

1.22.9 MySQL C API

1.22.10 MySQL PHP API

1.22.11 MySQL Perl API

1.22.12 MySQL Python API

1.22.13 MySQL Ruby API

1.22.14 MySQL Tcl API

1.22.15 MySQL Eiffel Wrapper

1.23 Extending MySQL

1.23.1 MySQL Internals

1.23.2 The MySQL Plugin API

1.23.3 Adding New Functions to MySQL 

1.23.4 Debugging and Porting MySQL 

1.24 MySQL Enterprise Monitor

1.25 MySQL Enterprise Backup

1.26 MySQL Workbench

1.27 MySQL for Excel

1.27.1 Installing and Configuring

1.27.2 Edit MySQL Data

1.27.3 Import MySQL Data

1.27.4 Append MySQL Data

1.27.5 Export MySQL Data

1.28 A. Licenses for Third-Party Components

1.28.1 Anti-Contrib License

1.28.2 ANTLR 3 License

1.28.3 ANTLR 3.3 License

1.28.4 Boost Library License

1.28.5 dtoa.c License

1.28.6 Editing Library (libedit) License

1.28.7 FindGTest.cmake License

1.28.8 Fred Fish's Dbug Library License

1.28.9 getarg License

1.28.10 GLib License (for MySQL Proxy)

1.28.11 GNU General Public License Version 2.0, June 1991

1.28.12 GNU Lesser General Public License Version 2.1, February 1999

1.28.13 GNU Libtool License

1.28.14 GNU Readline License

1.28.15 Google Controlling Master Thread I/O Rate Patch License

1.28.16 Google Perftools (TCMalloc Utility) License

1.28.17 Google SMP Patch License

1.28.18 lib_sql.cc License

1.28.19 Libaio License

1.28.20 libevent License

1.28.21 Libiconv License

1.28.22 libintl License

1.28.23 Linux-PAM License

1.28.24 LPeg Library License

1.28.25 Lua (libiua) License

1.28.26 LuaFileSystem Library License

1.28.27 md5 (Message-Digest Algorithm 5) License

1.28.28 memcached License

1.28.29 nt_serv (Windows NT Service class library) License

1.28.30 OpenPAM License

1.28.31 Paramiko License

1.28.32 PCRE License

1.28.33 Percona Multiple I/O Threads Patch License

1.28.34 Python License

1.28.35 Red HAT RPM Spec File License

1.28.36 RegEX-Spencer Library License

1.28.37 RFC 3174 - US Secure Hash Algorithm 1 (SHA1) License

1.28.38 Richard A. O'Keefe String Library License

1.28.39 SHA-1 in C License

1.28.40 Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) License

1.28.41 zlib License

1.28.42 ZLIP.NET License

1.29 B. MySQL 5.5 Frequently Asked Questions

1.29.1 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: General

1.29.2 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Storage Engines

1.29.3 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Server SQL Mode

1.29.4 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Stored Procedures and Functions

1.29.5 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Triggers

1.29.6 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Views

1.29.7 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: INFORMATION_SCHEMA

1.29.8 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Migration

1.29.9 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Security

1.29.10 MySQL FAQ: MySQL 5.5 and MySQL Cluster

1.29.11 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: MySQL Chinese, Japanese, and Korean Character Set

1.29.12 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Connectors & APIs

1.29.13 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Replication

1.29.14 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: MySQL Enterprise Scalability Thread Pool

1.29.15 MySQL 5.5 FAQ: MySQL, DRBD, and Heartbeat

1.30 C. Errors, Error Codes, and Common Problems

1.30.1 Sources of Error Information

1.30.2 Types of Error Values

1.30.3 Server Error Codes and Messages

1.30.4 Client Error Codes and Messages

1.30.5 Problems and Common Errors

1.31 D. MySQL Change History

1.31.1 Changes in Release 5.5.x (Production)

1.31.2 MySQL Connector/ODBC (MyODBC) Change History

1.31.3 MySQL Connector/Net Change History

1.31.4 MySQL Visual Studio Plugin Change History

1.31.5 MySQL Connector/J Change History

1.31.6 MySQL Connector/C++ Change History

1.31.7 MySQL Proxy Change History

1.31.8 MySQL for Excel Change History

1.31.9 MySQL Installer Change History

1.32 E. Restrictions and Limits

1.32.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs

1.32.2 Restrictions on Condition Handling

1.32.3 Restrictions on Server-Side Cursors

1.32.4 Restrictions on Subqueries

1.32.5 Restrictions on Views

1.32.6 Restrictions on XA Transactions

1.32.7 Restrictions on Character Sets

1.32.8 Restrictions on Performance Schema

1.32.9 Restrictions on Pluggable Authentication

1.32.10 Limits in MySQL

1.33 F. MySQL Glossary

1.34 General Index

1.35 C Function Index

1.36 Command Index

1.37 Function Index

1.38 INFORMATION_SCHEMA Index

1.39 Transaction Isolation Level Index

1.40 Join Types Index

1.41 Operator Index

1.42 Option Index
```

It is divided into sections, subsections and sub subsections. But the output to PDF comes out as a 2 page document as follows (the first page is blank):

```
￼1
1 A2:
1.1 General Information
1.1.1 About This Manual
1.1.2 Typographical and Syntax Conventions
1.1.3 Overview of the MySQL Database Management System
1.1.4 What Is New in MySQL 5.5
1.1.5 MySQL Development History
1.1.6 MySQL Information Sources
1.1.7 How to Report Bugs or Problems
1.1.8 MySQL Standards Compliance
1.1.9 Credits
1.2 Installing and Upgrading MySQL
1.2.1 General Installation Guidance
1.2.2 Installing MySQL from Generic Binaries on Unix/Linux
1.2.3 Intalling MySQL on Microsoft Windows
1.2.4 Intalling MySQL on Mac OS X
1.2.5 Intalling MySQL on Linux
1.2.6 Intalling MySQL Using Unbreakable Linux Network (ULN)
1.2.7 Intalling MySQL on Solaris and OpenSolaris
1.2.8 Intalling MySQL on HP-UX
1.2.9 Intalling MySQL on FreeBSD
1.2.10 Intalling MySQL from Source
1.2.11 Postinstallation Setup and Testing
1.2.12 Upgrading or Downgrading MySQL
1.2.13 Environment Variables
1.2.14 Perl Installation Notes
1.3 Tutorial
1.3.1 Connecting to and Disconnecting from the Server
1.3.2 Entering Queries
1.3.3 Creating and Using a Database
1.3.4 Getting Information About Databases and Tables
2
1.3.5 Using MySQL in Batch Mode
1.3.6 Examples of Common Queries
1.3.7 Using MySQL with Apache
1.4 MySQL Programs
1.4.1 Overview of MySQL Programs
1 A2:
```

￼Not sure what's going on. Why is LyX messing up with the output? (Just to clarify, the output document does not have all the text. It gets cut down to one page; the first page is empty and the second page has some of the text, resulting in a 2 page document.)

The document layout is set to fancy. Everything else is on its default settings.

I'd really appreciate help on this. And I apologize if this has already been asked before.

Here's the file in .lyx format:
http://www.4shared.com/file/bDbqV2kd/testTex1.html

Here's the output to the file in PDF:
http://www.4shared.com/office/bazrKiBG/testTex1.html

If 4shared asks for an account and password, please use the following that I created just for you guys:

User Email: paininbuttocks2012@gmail.com
Password: passwordfortex

Here's the link to the whole LyX document (as a simple text file) on pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/iPPzVYmw

Comment: If all else fails, we need to be able to replicate the problem in order to find an adequate solution. And, as-is, this is not possible, since nothing in the post is in LyX format. You may need to post the `.lyx` file, as well as specify the version of LyX you're using (hopefully 2.0.4).

Comment: @Werner It is 2.0.4. How do I post the file, to an outside server and provide the link here? (That's what I intended to do but couldn't figure out how or where to post it.)

Comment: That's correct, an outside server. Some people also post text-based output to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: If you open the .lyx-file in a text editor you'll find it's just plain text, so you could possibly copy the whole thing into your question. (There is a limit to how many characters a question can have though, so if your file is long, you'd have to use something like Pastebin.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have pasted the whole thing in the first "code" block. I am just going to upload the file on 4shared and provide links for it.

Comment: 4shared seems to require login, can you find an alternative? Also, while that may be all you see inside LyX, a .lyx-file doesn't look like that if you open it in a text editor, such as Notepad or Gedit.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm sorry I misunderstood you before. I will paste the whole thing on pastebin. Once I realized 4shared asked for a login, I created one just for here. I have provided the login details in the body of the question. Once I put it up on pastebin, I will put up its link in the body.

Comment: It seems that LaTeX won't insert page breaks between subsections and sections, if there isn't any other text there as well. Hence, all the sections/subsections will just be one big block, that overflows the second page. If you're going to add text in each subsection later, don't worry about it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are spot on about that. Thank you. I will be adding text to each section later however some of the subsections will remain as they are. And I see that LaTeX considers those subsections as one big block too if there is no text in between them. Is there a way to fix this problem or should I look at maybe using some other category apart from "subsection"?

Comment: The thing is that LaTeX avoids page breaks after headings, because such orphan section headings are a bad thing. I think there is some setting to change that, but I don't know it. However, if you won't have any content it looks more like a list of things, so perhaps a numbered list instead?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I will just change the subsections to a numbered list. If you could write this comment ("It seems that LaTeX won't insert page breaks between subsections and sections, if there isn't any other text there as well...") as an answer, I will accept it as the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your time, patience and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have a long list of sections and subsections without any content between them. LaTeX won't add page breaks immediately after section headings, so the result is that all the (sub)sections become one big block that overflows the page.

If content is to be added, then the problem can be ignored for the time being, as the new content will allow page breaks. If the subsections won't have any content, then it looks more like a numbered list of sorts, and as such it would be more appropriate to use just that, a numbered list.

Comment: +1 just add `bla` into each subsection, and don't forget to remove all `bla`s at the right moment :)